# jquery - Mailchimp Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json

Tags: jquery, mailchimp, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to use Mailchimps post-json in an ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://example.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=(MY LIST ID)&amp;id=(SOME SORT OF ID)',
                data: {'EMAIL' : $("#email").val()},
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (err) { 
                    alert('Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later.');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  
                  
                }
              });
```

But I get this error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with
> MIME type application/json

How can I get past this on my side?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to add `&c=? at the end of url: id=(SOME SORT OF ID)&c=?`.